# How can i run a project after clonning from github?

Tags: django, github

I want to run a specific project after downloading it from Github. I read all the instructions also but i didn't understand how to run it with my existing interpreter. I have installed all the required packages also. Please help someone and please don't flag my comment as useless.

[Django Job Portal](https://github.com/manjurulhoque/django-job-portal)

Comment: Install requirements and run a server. Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2):

Took a quick look and it seems to be a case of inadequate documentation (none?), that hopefully gets remedied as the project matures. At a very quick glance at the code, it seems to be a standard app (jobsapp tree). So you might start playing with it by creating a Django virtual environment containing its requirements, putting the jobsapp tree into the relevant place (where `startapp name` would put name) and including its urls into that environment's master urls.py file. Also jobsapp (or jobs?) in INSTALLED_APPS in the master settings.py

Then, makemigrations and migrate, to create its DB tables. If makemigrations crashes, I've clearly forgotten something.

Note, it's urls.py identifies itself as jobs, not jobsapp. Not sure of the implications.

Then either fire up runserver and point a web-browser at it, or fire up its tests. If tests fail or the test server crashes, you'll have to work out why.  You will soon know if it is useful to yourself, or for whatever reason not functioning well enough to spend more of your time time on.

Reading the installation instructions for a well-known widely-used third party app like django-filters may be helpful. Modulo some names, installation instructions will be pretty much the same for any well-written app (i.e. one that sticks to the conventions).

Answer (score 0):

Let us do it together, use the following commands

1. Grab a copy of the project. using this command `git clone new_project.git`
2. Create a virtual environment and install dependencies.using  `mkvirtualenv new_project` and `pip install -r requirements.txt`

3.Duplicate new_project/new_project/local_settings_example.py and save as `local_settings.py.`

4.Enter your database settings in local_settings.py.

5. Initialize your database. using this `python ./manage.py syncdb` or

   `python ./manage.py migrate`

If your app has a custom user model, you'll need to create a new superuser for the admin. use this command to create the superuser `python ./manage.py createsuperuser`

6. Run the development server to verify everything is working.using this command `python ./manage.py runserver`

happy coding my fellow developer

Comment: Thank you brother....I am new to github so i have a lot of doubt regarding github.

Comment: if you found my answer of help, please vote it so that it can help other future developers looking for the same solution

Comment: Yes brother sure